# NSDate From .NET Ticks Since Jan 1, 0001

Tags: ios, objective-c, .net, timestamp, nsdate

I'm working with an API that returns timestamps in .NET ticks format which I believe is 100 nanoseconds since Jan 1, 0001.  This ends up with an extremely large number such as 635492330000000 (just typing from memory).

When I get the number from the API it's in NSNumber but it's too big to convert to an Integer on a 32 bit device to do math and convert it into seconds.  How can I convert it to an NSDate?

Comment: Can't your data source be changed? I can't imagine a default data type capable of holding such a large number. And are you sure your API returns ticks since Jan 1, 0001 and not some other reference date?

Comment: @Aaron after lot of corrections see my edited answer it is calculating correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `long long` it can handle the large number like this.You can Convert from `NSSNumber` `NSLog(@"%lld", [date longlongValue]);`

Convert it to date.

```
NSNumber *dateNumber = @(635492330000000);   //Your Number
NSDate *date =  [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: ([dateNumber longLongValue]-621355968000000L)/10000.0];  //621355968000000L are ticks
```

This will calculate from 1 January 0001
This will give date as `2014-10-18 12:43:20 +0000`

Comment: And how would that be converted to an `NSDate`?

Comment: Nope, incorrect. Won't work. And there's no point in converting a long long to a double, you don't gain anything. In fact double might not even hold all of the number in long long.

Comment: double can also hold large number like this.After division it is giving `635492.32999999996` which is far more correct as we have to do this in seconds and nsdate is giving correct value `2001-01-08 08:31:32 +0000`

Comment: Incorrect. Ticks are counted starting from Jan 1, 0001. The reference date `NSDate` talks about is Jan 1, 2001.